# How to describe this font feature in English?

Tags: word-request

I am trying to find one word to say one thing but cannot.
Let's see:

[image]

I've tried googling for one font that has this feature but I have not managed to so far. Can someone please help?

Comment: In cattle brands (North America) "lazy A".

Comment: BTW, for the original A, you would say it's "upright" or "rightside up", maybe "standing".

Comment: Your "upside down" could also be "inverted".

Comment: @JAB, the upright A could also be inverted! :->

Comment: @Peter1807 An inverted ∀?

Comment: Note that "inverted" could take on a different meaning for letters that are not bilaterally symmetric: e.g. `p` resembles a *rotated* `d`, but `q` resembles an *inverted* `d`.

Comment: @JAB, because A has so much symmetry it's not clear whether OP's "upside down" is inverted or *turned* (which is the standard term for letters which have been rotated by 180 degrees).

Comment: @JAB no, mirrored on a vertical axis :D

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Either of these might work:

- The third letter is **sideways**.
- The third letter is **rotated 90 degrees**.

I suppose you could also say:

- The third letter is **tilted at a right angle**.

but I don’t think you’ll have as much luck with that one on Google.

Comment: Yes, these. Note that for the second, you might want to say *rotated 90 degrees **clockwise*** if you need to be very precise (e.g. if you're trying to describe a graphic that you need reproduced) and could also just say ***rotated*** if you don't need much precision at all, as most folks will assume a rotation of approximately 90° if you don't specify (in very loose terms, more than that would be *upside down* and less would be *tilted*).

Comment: I think most people, in day-to-day speech, would go with the first option (sideways). As @1006a commented, adding "clockwise" (or "counter-clockwise"/"anti-clockwise") makes option 2 the most precise -- tells which "sideways" it is, and by how much (exactly 90 degrees). I wouldn't normally use "tilted" unless referring to something that's rotated less than 90 degrees, and probably only less than 45 degrees: the point at which the letter becomes more "sideways" than "upright".

Comment: The first option is [what Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_of_text), claiming to be based on the Unicode standard. I haven't independently verified this.

Comment: How about *Horizontal*?

Comment: @JonasB - I don't think _horizontal_ is a good suggestion. [This picture](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/01/images/Text_Figure5.gif) explains why.

Answer (score 16):

The official language in the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/reports/tr50/) uses the terms “sideways” and the detailed description “displayed sideways, rotated 90 degrees clockwise”.  I'm sure they spent a lot of time arguing over the best words to use!

The simple adjective **sideways** is understandable without confusion.  The description **rotated clockwise** is unambiguous with respect to which side.

Comment: "The description rotated clockwise is unambiguous." It's extremely ambiguous if you don't specify a degree of rotation

Comment: @Kevin "Rotate left" and "right" are pretty standard terms in graphics editing programs, and they don't need to specify 90° to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 15):

That would be ***a sideways A***. Not a perfect way to say it, but I think it will work in this case.

Answer (score 13):

One way of describing this would be to say "A is **on its side**"

Answer (score 3):

It might be good to include what direction it's rotated: "Rotated 90 degrees clockwise."

Answer (score 2):

It's a form of a vertical font or vertical typography. Vertical typography can have the characters 'upright', but the text is printed vertically. A variant is to print the words rotated 90 degrees to the right or left.

Answer (score 0):

To say it colloquially, you could say "The capital letter A is lying down" or a similar phrase that implies resting or sleeping.

The visual image of that might help cross linguistic boundries.